# Static RecyclerView header

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to writing android app's in Kotlin.

I have  a project to maintaince in which I have RecyclerView. I want my first item on the view to be sticky, meaning it will be constantly visible even when scrolling. I've seen some external libraries that will add/remove headers when reaching them with scroll, but that seems too complex. Is there a simple way to stick one view to the top constantly?

I've tried creating decorators and pulling out this particular view outside of my recyclerview, but that didn't work as intended.